# What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a subset of the semiring to be sub- semiring

Tags: semiring

Is there any smaller sort of things (without proving semiring axioms ) to ascertain that a subset $R$ of the semiring $S$ is sub-semiring ? Or, What is the necessary and sufficient condition for a subset of the semiring to be sub- semiring ?

Comment: For every $a$ and $b$ in the semiring, $0$, $1$, $ab$ and $a+b$ should be in the semiring. I think that it is sufficient.

Comment: @ajotatxe how does distributive property inherit from the semiring?